# How can I remove the space between the dropdown-toggle button and dropdown-menu elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Why is there a space between dropdown-toggle button and dropdown-menu?How can I remove this space? The box-shadow hides the space, but when the box-shadow is removed, you can see the space easily. This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
          .btn, button {
            box-shadow: none !important;
          }
        </style>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button
                    class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
                    type="button"
                    id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                >
                    Dropdown button
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="vertical-align: top;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                            >Something else here</a
                        >
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: edited the css code to make the space visible easily

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927651/how-to-remove-gap-between-dropdown-and-dropdown-menu) answer your question?

Comment: my problem occurs in desktop, not in mobile

Comment: when i inspected the web page i saw bootstrap adds position and transform to the dropdown-menu. I didn't find any css that can include this. So I guess this is happening because of javascript...

Comment: It was simply a design choice by the Bootstrap team. What problem are you trying to solve? Instead of asking why they did it (which no one knows with certainty), ask about your problem.

Comment: I asked about my problem, read the question. I didn't ask why does bootstrap give a space between dropdown-menu and dropdown-toggle, I asked how to remove the space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the gap between the toggle element and the dropdown, apply this CSS. It's a rare case where using `!important` seems appropriate, since the original styles are applied inline by the Bootstrap script.

Optionally apply some border-radius overrides to visually combine the elements when open.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px) !important;
}

/* optional */
body .dropdown-toggle.show {
  border-radius: .25rem .25rem 0 0;
}

body .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0 .25rem .25rem .25rem;
}
/* end optional */

.btn,
button {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown button
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="vertical-align: top;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .dropdown-menu.show {
    transform: translate(0px, 40px);
}
```

This is what pushes the menu down when you click the toggle

Comment: Yeah I know that. But I don't know how to remove that.

Comment: you can't remove it (i guess adding adding a click listener with JS and removing the class would work but it's really a bad idea here), it's default Bootstrap. Just write your own CSS to remove the gap

Comment: I tried to write my own css, but I am unable to do this. I guess it is happening because of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me using Bootstrap 5.2.1.

However, I got it to work using simply:

```
.dropdown-menu {margin-top: -2px!important;}
```